# ChartJs , Trazar lineas rectas en bar chart

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, canvas, chart.js

**LO ESPERADO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Poder trazar lineas horizontales con labels y colores como se ven en la foto.
2. Establecer escala estática de 0 a 300.

**Mi código actual:**

*JS*

```
var data = {
            labels: ["UNO"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Semestre 2017-I",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: [10]
                }
            ]
        };            

var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx");

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
<canvas id="ctx" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eayb7Lhf/

Comment: ¿Debo usar alguna librería extra?